How can volume be calculated if one parameter is undefined because another goes to zero.
I have the following equations:
$$V = \int^{2\pi}_0\int^{r_i}_0hrdrd\phi$$
$$hr = \frac{R^2\sin^3\beta}{(1-\cos\beta\cos\phi)^2}$$
and
$$r_i = \frac{R\sin\beta}{1- \cos\beta\cos\phi}$$
When the double integrals are evaluated, $R$ and $\beta$ are constant.
Referring to the  post at Solve a double integral where one of the limits contains a variable
the analytical solution of the double integral is
$$V=\pi\frac{2+\cos^2\beta}{\sin^5\beta}$$
The inner integration for Eq. 1 has limits of $0$ to $r_i$.  However, if $r = 0$, then if Eq. 2 is solved for $h$, $h$ is undefined.
So, if this is the case how is it that the double integral was able to achieve a finite solution?  It does appear to be true, however, that while $h$ is undefined when $r = 0$, the product $hr$ is not undefined.  Is this the reason why it is possible to solve for the volume?

Is equation 2 true for all positive r? Then the discontinuity at $r=0$ doesn't affect the integral.

Yes Eq. 2 is true.  Is there some theory somewhere regarding your statement.  I want to be able to understand and explain why this is so. Thanks.

If you have an integrable function and you change exactly one value of the function, the function stays integrable and the integral stays the same. This can be proven using the definition of the integrals as a limit of Riemann sums.

You're not integrating $h$; you're integrating $hr$. And if I understand correctly, $hr$ is independent of $r$ for all $r>0$. Then you can extend $hr$ to have this same value at $r=0$, and the integral will be the same.
